# trigger table is not working , while updating table new record is not inserting in my sql database

Tags: mysql

> i want to insert a new record in the trigger table "livedata" when the
>   new record is inserted.if primary key value is not same it should
>   inserted as a new row in the livedata table. when i trying to insert
>   i'm not getting new record in the trigger table.

SQL query

```
DELIMITER $$
create TRIGGER update_livedata3
AFTER INSERT ON `Rawdata`
FOR EACH ROW
begin 
INSERT INTO Livedata(IMEI,updatedTime,latitude,longitude,speed,ignition,fuel,altitude,battery,runHrs,alert,distance) VALUES (NEW.IMEI,NEW.updatedTime, NEW.latitude,NEW. longitude,NEW.speed,NEW.ignition,NEW.fuel,NEW.altitude,NEW.battery,NEW.runHrs,NEW.alert,NEW.distance);
END$$
```

Comment: I doubt that IMEI = IMEI is useful and please add table defintion ALSO I would prefer a values clause over a set clause every time. AND the question is not clear if you need conditional insert then you should test for existence AND I would expect to see reference to NEW. and possiblyOLD. values in an update trigger. AND in which table does the primary key exist referenced in the question? .Please add table defintions, sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: "when i trying to insert": you made a "BEFORE UPDATE"-trigger, it runs when you update a row (using `update ...`), not when you insert.

Comment: @Solarflare i have updated my query, it works but inserting new row. but i wanted to update it when the imei is available or else need to insert new row in livedata table